# function replace substring returns incorrect answer

Tags: c, string, replace, substring

I have a program replacing a substring in a string. The idea is to find the `string_to_be_replaced` in `original_string`, then `realloc` the `new_string` and connect it to `replace_by` string. It works for some cases but in some cases like below, it return wrong answer:

Input:

> ```
> abc def ghi //orginal string
>
> (a blank space) //string to be replaced
>
> 1234 //replace by
> ```

Output:

> ```
> abc1234defT123ghi
> ```

Expected output:

> ```
> abc1234def1234ghi
> ```

When I debug it, I saw a wrong character has been filled in the `new_string` after the first replacement had been done.

Please tell me why does this happen and how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void fgetsWithoutNewline(char *s, size_t maxCount, FILE *fp);
bool sameString(char *original_tring, char *string_to_be_searched, size_t start);
char *replaceString(char *original_tring, char *string_to_be_replaced, char *replace_by);

int main()
{
    char *original_string = malloc(100);
    fgetsWithoutNewline(original_string, 99, stdin);

    char *string_to_be_replaced = malloc(100);
    fgetsWithoutNewline(string_to_be_replaced, 99, stdin);

    char *replace_by = malloc(100);
    fgetsWithoutNewline(replace_by, 99, stdin);

    char *s = replaceString(original_string, string_to_be_replaced, replace_by);
    printf("%s", s);

    free(original_string);
    free(string_to_be_replaced);
    free(replace_by);
    return 0;
}

void fgetsWithoutNewline(char *s, size_t maxCount, FILE *fp)
{
    if (fgets(s, maxCount, fp))
    {
        s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';
    }
    return;
}

char *replaceString(char *original_tring, char *string_to_be_replaced, char *replace_by)
{
    if (!original_tring || !string_to_be_replaced || !replace_by)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    char *new_string = malloc(strlen(original_tring));

    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(original_tring); i++, j++)
    {
        if (sameString(original_tring, string_to_be_replaced, i))
        {
            new_string = realloc(new_string, strlen(new_string) + strlen(replace_by) - strlen(string_to_be_replaced));
            strcat(new_string, replace_by);
            i += strlen(string_to_be_replaced) - 1;  // i and j use to track the last character of original string and new string
            j += strlen(replace_by) - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            new_string[j] = original_tring[i];
        }
    }
    return new_string;
}

bool sameString(char *original_tring, char *string_to_be_searched, size_t start)
{
    if (strlen(string_to_be_searched) + start > strlen(original_tring))
    {
        return false;
    }
    size_t end = strlen(string_to_be_searched) + start;
    for (size_t i = start, j = 0; i < end; i++, j++)
    {
        if (original_tring[i] != string_to_be_searched[j])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @P__J__ I mean like this `original_string="abc def ghi"`, `string_to_be_replaced=" "`, `replace_by="1234"`

Comment: @AJFerron I'm using windows 7 and gcc 8.1.0

Comment: you should avoid callin strlen in a loop. strcat is a very heavy function as well (as it always calculates both length). Use memcpy memmoe instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the symptoms are clear, the string is not being null terminated.

Try the follwing:

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Bkzx_csa8)

```
char *replaceString(char *original_tring, char *string_to_be_replaced, const char *replace_by)
{
    if (!original_tring || !string_to_be_replaced || !replace_by)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    char *new_string = malloc(strlen(original_tring));

    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(original_tring); i++, j++)
    {
        if (sameString(original_tring, string_to_be_replaced, i))
        {
            new_string = realloc(new_string, strlen(new_string) + strlen(replace_by) - strlen(string_to_be_replaced));
            strcat(new_string, replace_by);
            i += strlen(string_to_be_replaced) - 1;
            j += strlen(replace_by) - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            new_string[j] = original_tring[i];
        }
        new_string[j + 1] = '\0'; //here
    }  
    return new_string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you aren't adding the required `nul`-terminator character(s) to your `new_string` buffer (in the `replace_string` function). On systems that, just by chance, fill any new data 'created' by `malloc` or `realloc` with zeros, this will be hard to find; but this is *not* the standard behaviour, and you should *explicitly* ensure the `nul`-terminator is always there.

For the initial allocation of `new_string`, this *could* be done using the `calloc` function; however, as you (probably) call `realloc` to increase the size of the buffer at least once, you will have to make sure that the newly-added memory also has the `nul`, so you only really need to add that terminator at the of *every* run of the `for` loop:

```c
char* replaceString(char* original_tring, char* string_to_be_replaced, char* replace_by)
{
    if (!original_tring || !string_to_be_replaced || !replace_by) {
        return NULL;
    }
    char* new_string = malloc(strlen(original_tring));
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(original_tring); i++, j++) {
        if (sameString(original_tring, string_to_be_replaced, i)) {
            new_string = realloc(new_string, strlen(new_string) + strlen(replace_by) - strlen(string_to_be_replaced));
            strcat(new_string, replace_by);
            i += strlen(string_to_be_replaced) - 1;  // i and j use to track the last character of original string and new string
            j += strlen(replace_by) - 1;
        }
        else {
            new_string[j] = original_tring[i];
        }
        new_string[j + 1] = '\0';/// Add new nul-terminator!
    }
    return new_string;
}
```

Comment: I'm kidding, neve mind that, it was virtually at the same time.

Comment: We both deserve credit on this one, debugging is  a painstaking job.

Comment: @anastaciu I did once suggest a way of [sharing credit for simultaneous answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390197/10871073) but the idea wasn't well-received.

Comment: Well I like it, you make good points, not only in your post but in the comment section. Though I recognize the implementation can be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Your function (abstracting from the missing nul terminator) is very inefficient.

Below you have the functions

This one uses the same string to store the result:

```
char *stringreplace(char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *replace)
{
    size_t needleLen = strlen(needle);
    size_t replaceLen = strlen(replace);
    char *wrk = haystack;
    char *end = haystack + strlen(haystack);



    while((wrk = strstr(wrk, needle)))
    {
        memmove(wrk + replaceLen, wrk + needleLen, end - wrk + 1);
        memcpy(wrk, replace, replaceLen);
        wrk += replaceLen;
        end += replaceLen - needleLen;
    }
    return haystack;
}
```

This one is using dynamic allocation. Note that on many systems `malloc` and especially `realloc` are very expensive operation and it is often worth tto traverse the string twice and call only one malloc knowing the size of the resulting string.

```
char *dupstringreplace(const char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *replace)
{
    char *newhaystack = NULL;
    const char *wrk = haystack;
    char *newwrk;
    ssize_t occurences = 0;
    size_t needleLen = strlen(needle);
    size_t replaceLen = strlen(replace);

    while((wrk = strstr(wrk, needle)))
    {
        occurences++;
        wrk += needleLen;
    }
    newhaystack = malloc(strlen(haystack) + occurences * ((ssize_t)replaceLen - (ssize_t)needleLen) + 1);
    wrk = haystack;
    newwrk = newhaystack;
    while((wrk = strstr(wrk, needle)))
    {
        memcpy(newwrk, haystack, wrk - haystack);
        newwrk += wrk - haystack;
        memcpy(newwrk, replace, replaceLen);
        newwrk += replaceLen;
        wrk += needleLen;
        haystack = wrk;
    }
    strcpy(newwrk, haystack);
    return newhaystack;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/b4eyk_)