# How to replace '"' with "\"" in string in c?

Tags: c, json, escaping

I need to output some data in json format and that data may have '"' in it. Is there any fast or simple way to do this?

```
char* asd = "you need to update \"@world\"";
printf("{ \"asd\": \"%s\" }", escape_quotes(asd));
```

Something like that.

Comment: One thing I do if I want `"` inside a string literal is to define `char quote = '"'` and use `%c` in the string. I find it to be more readable. Another solution if the target language does not care whether you use single `'` or double `"` (for example html or javascript) is to use the single `'`. So `char* asd = "you need to update '@world'";`

Comment: It's just an example, I don't define data so I can't change it that way :/

Comment: you have functions replacing one ssubstring with another. Duplicating and not https://stackoverflow.com/a/62487483/6110094

Comment: @P__J__ A generalized substring replacement function isn't the most efficient way of escaping certain characters. Admittedly, in this case, just a single character value needs to be escaped, but in general there are multiple character values that need to be escaped in JSON strings.

Comment: @IanAbbott it is not char to char. I do not know if you see my deleted answer (I do not know what reputation is needed for that). OP explained that he want to do a bit more complicated escape. escape  a char by sequence of chars. Then it is same efficient or the penalty is minimal

Comment: @IanAbbott it is the reson why I have deleted my answer and marked as a dupe

Comment: @P__J__ I'm just saying there may be better ways to solve this particular problem than the answers in the dupe.